# What `TRANSACTION ACTIVE .. sec ` means in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, deadlock, mybatis

> *** (2) TRANSACTION:
> TRANSACTION 4693337, ACTIVE 9991 sec fetching rows

We use Spring Boot and MyBatis as BackEnd to provide RESTful service.

Now we often encouter the `CannotAcquireLockException` RuntimeExcetion.

Firstly, we think we use `@Transaction` too often.

Seeing the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output, we find deadlock, and the quoted `ACTIVE` TRANSACTION is so long.

So, what `9991 sec` relealy means?  Does it mean the time since the transaction started?

How to minimize it?

Comment: yes, its the time since the transaction started. Include the full output from `show engine innodb status`. Also include the SQL, `show create table {tablename}` for tables involved. Wheither `@Transaction` is used or not, everything in InnoDB is a transaction. Encapsulate what is needed to represent a business level view of an atomic operation. Handle failures. Improved indexing may help.

Comment: If index is the problem， why no slow sql lasts that long？And necessary indexes have been created I think  @danblack